# How to execute a join query by an AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a drop-down list, from this list I have to send an ajax request to the database and I have run a join query over the request. However, when I check my response using `alert()` it only shows `[object][Object]`.

Here is my AJAX request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#client_id').on('change',function(){
        var id=$(this).val();
  //alert(id);
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('getcheque')}}",
            method:'post',
            data:{
              id: id,
              '_token':"{{csrf_token()}}"
            },
            success:function(response)
            {
                //console.log(response);
                alert(response);
            }
        });

    });
    //end client part

});
```

and here is my ajax request method.

```
public function get_cheque(Request $request)
{
    $id=$request->id;
    $cdata=DB::table('directcheques')
            ->join('clients', 'directcheques.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->join('banks', 'directcheques.bank_id', '=', 'banks.id')
            ->select('directcheques.*', 'clients.*', 'banks.*')
            ->where('directcheques.id',$id)
            ->get();

    return $cdata;
}
```

Comment: Javascript alert doesn't show complete object details instead it shows `[object][Object]`. Try `console.log` and add response in your question.

Comment: Try `echo json_encode($cdata)` on your php instead of returning it

Comment: echo json_encode it's show  [{"id":2,"client_id":4,"bank_id":2,"cheq_amt":9000,"cheq_no":7809,"collc_date":"2017-11-22","collc_by":null,"status":0,"created_at":"2017-11-19 07:54:36","updated_at":"2017-11-19 07:54:36","client_name":"majeddue","cont_no":"6742709","addr":"dhaka","bank_name":"TestBank","branch_name":"testbranch"}]

Comment: but, i can't access specific value from this array..

Comment: response.branch_name this wont work, since your response is an array. one way you call reset($array) before sent it or calling response[0].branch_name might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is an array calling `response[0].branch_name` might work. 
If you are having multiple records then you need to iterate using [for each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

If it is laravel and your expected response contain only one record , instead of get() use following, then you can call response.branch_name

```
$cdata=DB::table('directcheques')
        ->join('clients', 'directcheques.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
        ->join('banks', 'directcheques.bank_id', '=', 'banks.id')
        ->select('directcheques.*', 'clients.*', 'banks.*')
        ->where('directcheques.id',$id)
        ->first(); //change to first only if you need one record.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, `return` only works if you are using the returned value with another `php` function.

When using `Ajax` you should use `echo/print` instead of `return`.

like below,

```
public function get_cheque(Request $request)
{
    $id=$request->id;
    $cdata=DB::table('directcheques')
            ->join('clients', 'directcheques.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->join('banks', 'directcheques.bank_id', '=', 'banks.id')
            ->select('directcheques.*', 'clients.*', 'banks.*')
            ->where('directcheques.id',$id)
            ->get();

    echo json_encode($cdata);
}
```

In your `Ajax` parse JSON,

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: but i can't access any specific field from this json array. i have tried  console.log(response.branch_name); this way. but it's show undefined.

Comment: you have to decode the JSON on the client side, using JSON.parse, like this var data = JSON.parse(response);